# Sass-loader PrependData in angular cli 8 using custom-webpack throws error

Tags: webpack, angular-cli, angular8, angular-cli-v8

angular.json config

[image]

webpack.config.js file

[image]

Error Message

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue is due to sass-loader version, the webpack config is related to sass-loader 8.0.0 and angular cli using is sass-loader 7.0.2 by changing **prependData** to **data** fixed the issue